# Variable length arithmetic calculator WITHOUT using strings?

Tags: c, calculator

I'm trying to create a calculator that solves arithmetic expressions of different lengths (e.g. 2+3/4 or 7*8/2+12-14), and I was wondering if it was possible to do so without the use of strings.

I've found countless tutorials explaining how to make a simple calculator with only two numbers and an operator, and I've also found examples using sscanf and strings to get the input.

However, my question is: Is there a way (is it even possible) to get variable length inputs without using strings?

At first I thought i could simply add more specifiers:

```
int num1 , num2, num3;
char op1, op2;

printf("Please enter your equation to evaluate: ");
scanf("%d%c%d%c%d", &num1, &op1, &num2, &op2, &num3);
```

but obviously, that doesn't work for equations longer than 3 numbers or less than 3 numbers.
I was also thinking of perhaps using some sort of recursive function, but I'm not sure how I would do that if I need to ask for the entire equation up front?

Comment: You can try to do your own parser and use the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: Read one character at a time.

Comment: Without using strings, sure, you could store each token as a `char`, however - you'll need a descent parser. It is preferable to convert the expression to polish notation and then build a expression tree with a stack structure.

Comment: Is there any way to compile a program without using compiler?

Comment: As mentioned before, you need to _parse_ the input string (equation) into some form, such as RPN. Be specific about what kind of rules the equation is to follow: simple left-to-right or algebraic (multiply and divide before add and subtract). Are parentheses to be allowed? Other operators than `+ - * /`? If your operands are nothing but numbers, you can probably largely evaluate them on the fly (although with algebraic (stack based) notation, not all can be immediately evaluated). Finally, don't skimp on error detection, reporting, and even fixup -- there are many more **wrong** ways to enter!

Comment: Possible by state transition by entering one by one(char).

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to read ASCII from user input, or from command line arguments, then you're pretty inescapably in the world of strings. What you *can* do is convert them into something else as early as possible.

You could abandon ASCII altogether and define a binary file format.

For example, you might say that each pair of two bytes is a token. The first byte is an element type ( signed integer, unsigned integer, float, operator), the second byte is the value.

Pseudocode:

```
while(!done) {
  int type = read(f);
  int value = read(f);
  switch(type) {
      case TYPE_INTEGER:
          push_to_stack(value);
          break;
      case TYPE_FLOAT:
          push_to_stack_as_float(value);
          break;
      case TYPE_OPERATOR:
          execute_operator(value);
          break;
  }
}
```

Quite *why* you would force yourself down this route, I don't know. You'd probably find yourself wanting to write a program to convert ASCII input into your binary file format; which would use strings. So why did you run away from strings in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list of struct, every struct will have to contains a value OR a sub list, an operator (char?) and a reference to the next (and or before) char.

Then you just ask the user for a number (or "("/")"), and a operator sign. Every number + operator is a new element in list, every ( is a sub list, every ) is a return to superior list (you can even don't create a sublist, but elaborate it on the fly and return just the result, like a recursive function)

Also struct and code can be elaborated to support multiple parameter.